# Authenticate Ignite Openfire users against ASP.NET membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, membership, openfire

I was wondering if there was any simple way to authenticate Openfire users against my existing ASP.NET membership? I see that Openfire has a custom database integration guide [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html) 
but I don't think that it supports my current method of password security. Apparently some of my members have type 1 and some have type 2 password security. I'm not sure how that happened, but since they are inconsistent, I can't use one of Openfire's preset password security options. I'd need to query against my database to figure out how the password is stored and then apply the correct method of password authentication based on the type. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think what I'm going to do is try and convert all encrypted password users to use hashed passwords as I can't convert the other way because hashes can't be decrypted. Since ASP.NET uses SHA1 to hash the passwords and a salt, I should theoretically be able to check against the SHA1 hash and salt for a user's password. I'll play with the data some more and see what comes up.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work just yet. I've been busy with semester projects and other side projects. I hope to take a closer look soon at integrating the two authentication systems. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: I actually got it to work, it's three parts. Not that hard really, I'll post the solution tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's actually not that hard to get this to work. You need to create three new Java files, one for each of the following:

- One that implements AdminProvider.java (if you want to pull admins from the IIS database)
- One that implements UserProvider.java (to list all/active users from IIS)
- One that implements AuthProvider.java (to actually do the authentication)

Implementing the admin provdier and the user provider is straightfoward, just follow the JDBC examples that are provided. One thing to note is that the IIS databse is keyed off of some GUID, and the actual user account fields (E-mail, name, etc) are in a different table, so you have to do a query to figure out the IIS ID, then use that to figure out the rest of the account fields, ie.

`SELECT TOP 1 UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE LoweredUserName = ?`

Then to get the E-mail (after you have the IIS ID)

`SELECT TOP 1 Email FROM dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE UserId = ?`

Doing the actual authentication is very easy, just take the username given to you by openfire, clean it up (it's sometimes user@host -- the @host part is not really part of the username) and figure out the IIS ID based on the username you're given.

Then you can do a query to figure out the password & password hash

`SELECT TOP 1 Password, PasswordSalt FROM dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE UserId = ?`

With that you have all you need to encrypt the password that's given to you -- here's the algorithm:

Note -- all of the utils are included with OpenFire (ie. `decodeHex(...)`, `Base64...`)

```
private static String encryptPassword(String password, String salt)
{
    if(password == null || salt == null)
        return "";

    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        byte[] src = Base64.decode(salt);
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.length + bytes.length];

        System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.length);
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.length, bytes.length);

        // Calculate the SHA1
        byte[] hashed = StringUtils.decodeHex(StringUtils.hash(dst, "SHA-1"));
        return Base64.encodeBytes(hashed);
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Log.error("UTF-16LE encoding not suported");
    }

    return "";
}
```

Just compare the result of this function with the IIS database's password field and you'll be off and running.

Another thing to note with the Admin provider: the AdminManager that openfire uses caches the results. It looks like the results get cached when the system starts -- so it's not really possible to keep the list of admins in sync with IIS. I'm still mulling over that one to figure out what the best approach will be. I might just remove the caching all together (AdminManager just holds a list of admins in memory.)

Once you get everything setup, just change a few properties in the config for openfire to connect it to your solution, ex.

```
provider.admin.className --> org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.IISAdminProvider
provider.auth.className --> org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.IISAuthProvider
provider.user.className --> org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.IISUserProvider
```

I added a few more properties for the IIS database username/password as well as some variables for what the name of my admin group is, etc. Just follow the JDBC examples and it's very easy. Note that after you change the `provider.*` properties in the openfire config you won't be able to login with the default admin anymore -- if something is messed up you'll have to go back into the database and change the config (in the `dbo.ofProperty` table of your openfire DB.)

Comment: I'm wondering if you can post some links to documentation on how to implement the providers and where you found the samples.  Don't know if you'd be willing to share your source code, but there aren't many good examples on the web and I haven't found any comprehensive documentation on this.

Comment: I would just post the code online -- but unfortunately I wrote it for work so it's not really mine to post. I just followed the documentation on the OpenFire website, along with the files I mentioned in my post. It's really not difficult to do -- the hardest part is transforming the clear text password into one that can compared against the IIS database, so that's why I posted that code here...

Comment: Could you provide links to the docs in question?  Would be much appreciated!

Comment: They aren't that helpful.... but here you go http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html. It's more helpful to follow the JDBC driver that is provided and just modify it (you really dont have to make many modifications) -- use Plain as the password hash type.

Comment: Thanks for the info and follow up.  I stumbled a bit with eclipse but figured it out in the end.

Comment: Oh yeah, I never figured out how to setup Openfire with eclipse, I just wrote the code the old fashioned way -- with Notepad++ and the command line!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I apologize for the late response. I haven't had the chance to try this approach out yet, but from what you said in your answer, it doesn't seem too difficult to get the two providers working. I'll be sure to mark your answer after I've been able to make the providers work together.

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to mark this as the answer. Thanks for your hard work!